# IoU keras (backend tensorflow) feed dict for placeholder error (tensor.eval()

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras, keras-2

I have error when I tried to create custom metric for keras (Intersection over union).
I want to find intersection over union of two images (tensors)

```
def IoU(y_true,y_pred):
    y_true_f = K.flatten(y_true)
    y_pred_f = K.flatten(y_pred)
    #assert len(y_true_f) != len(y_pred_f)
    y_true_f = y_true_f.eval(session = K.get_session())
    y_pred_f = y_pred_f.eval(session = K.get_session())
    union1 = [i  for i,j in zip(y_true_f,y_pred_f) if i != j]
    union2 = [j  for i,j in zip(y_true_f,y_pred_f) if i != j]
    intersection = [i for i,j in zip(y_true_f,y_pred_f) if i == j]
    unionAll = union1 + union2 + intersection
    return (np.sum(intersection) + smooth) / float(np.sum(unionAll)+ smooth)
```

The **error** I get:

> InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value
>   for placeholder tensor 'activation_1_target' with dtype float and
>   shape [?,?,?]      [[Node: activation_1_target =
>   Placeholderdtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,?,?],
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"]]   [[Node: metrics/IoU/Reshape/_5 = _Recvclient_terminated=false,
>   recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0",
>   send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0",
>   send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_8_metrics/IoU/Reshape",
>   tensor_type=DT_FLOAT,
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]]

Answer (score 0):

```
eps = 1.
def iou(y_true, y_pred):
   y_true_f = K.flatten(y_true)
   y_pred_f = K.flatten(y_pred)
   intersection = K.sum(y_true_f*y_pred_f)
   union = K.sum(y_true_f)+K.sum(y_pred_f)-intersection+eps
   return intersection/union
```